# reading csv file in python?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, machine-learning

i am working on a machine learning project where i am supposed to read a csv file to build a linear regression model and here is i read the csv file

```
data_test = pd.read_csv("/media/halawa/93B77F681EC1B4D2/GUC/Semster 8/CSEN 1022 Machine Learning/2/test.csv",delimiter=",", header=0)
```

but when i run i got this error

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/halawa/PycharmProjects/ML/evergreen.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/halawa/PycharmProjects/ML/evergreen.py", line 24, in <module>
data_test = pd.read_csv("/media/halawa/93B77F681EC1B4D2/GUC/Semster 8/CSEN 1022 Machine Learning/2/test.csv",delimiter=",", header=0)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 470, in parser_f
return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 256, in _read
return parser.read()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 715, in read
ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1164, in read
data = self._reader.read(nrows)
File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 758, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas/parser.c:7411)
File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 780, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas/parser.c:7651)
File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 833, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas/parser.c:8268)
File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 820, in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas/parser.c:8142)
File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 1758, in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas/parser.c:20728)
pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 3, saw 8


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Looks like that panda library is expecting a specific CSV structure, which isn't given, and fails internally. Are you required to not use the default python [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html)?

Comment: it is ok but could you please give me the line of code to use in my case because i am kinda new to python ?

Comment: The Python documentation has an example section. They give a pretty good overview of the usage

Comment: I don't think a "line of code" is going to help you here. The error you got says quite clearly that `Expected 3 fields in line 3, saw 8`. So what is line 3 of your input file? Why are you expecting 3 fields when there are actually 8?

Comment: Please post either the complete raw data or the first few lines, trying to reverse engineer your data from the error is impossible

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that your CSV doesn't have a consistent number of fields on each line. For example, it appears that the first line has 3 fields

```
x,y,z
```

While the third line has 8

```
x,y,z,a,b,c,d,e
```

You will need to fix your source CSV file to avoid this error.

Alternatively, if you know that you have 8 fields max, and are ok with some lines missing fields you can use `names`:

```
data_test = pd.read_csv("/media/halawa/93B77F681EC1B4D2/GUC/Semster 8/CSEN 1022 Machine Learning/2/test.csv",delimiter=",", header=0, names=list('abcdefgh'))
```

This parameter tells the CSV reader how many fields to expect, and the rest are filled in with a default value.

**EDIT:**

If your null columns are marked with a `?` then you should set the pandas `na_values` parameter like so:

```
data_test = pd.read_csv("/media/halawa/93B77F681EC1B4D2/GUC/Semster 8/CSEN 1022 Machine Learning/2/test.csv",delimiter=",", header=0, na_values=['?'])
```

Comment: actually it is a data file and i am not supposed to modify it and it is 3000 records which is impossible to modify , but yes there are null values inside the each line which is represented in "?" , is there any way to make it ignore this question mark or solve this problem ?

Comment: Ok updated my answer if I understood your comment correctly. If it doesn't work, please provide an concrete example of line 3 with the `?` nulls.

Comment: `culture_politics 0.135844 3.771428571 0.461538462 0.205128205 0.051282051 0 0.782051282 0 0 0.042857143 0 0.365961633 0.08 ? 1 62 0 382 39 2 0.128205128 0.176470588
`

Comment: my line is something like that and it is more bigger than 3 and 8

Comment: Ok looking at that line, I see that your `delimiter` is *not* a comma - it's actually a space, make sure you fix that first: `delimiter=" "`